# Elasticsearch is not returning anything through javascript API, Why?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

Below is my Autocomplete function it is supposed to return string from elasticsearch when someone types anything in search-box of my web page but It is not. And when I'm debugging in chrome (Break point at start of function Autocomplete) debugger stop after first line, why?

```
function Autocomplete(){
    var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
    var esclient = new elasticsearch.Client({
      host: 'localhost:9200',
      log: 'trace'
    });
    return esclient.search({
      index: "user",
      body: {
          "query": { "match_all": {} },
          "size": 1
            }
          }
    ).then(function (response) {
        var hits = response.hits.hits;
    });
}
```

Comment: you're not doing anything with the `hits` variable. What do you see if you print it out?

Comment: Nothing is being executed after first line.

Comment: could be a cross-domain issue?

Comment: Could you check the xhr sended when you try to autocomplete and provide us with a screenshot of your network panel ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.